# Select all text layers in Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, cs6

Before, one could select all text layers by selecting any text layer then Select> Similar layers

is this gone is cs6? (see img below)

[image]

If so, how can I do this now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In light of the new layer filtering features in Photoshop CS6, Adobe removed the Select→Similar Layers command. Hooray! It’s a rare thing when a menu gets shortened.
>   [Source](https://www.inkling.com/read/photoshop-cs6-missing-manual-lesa-snider-1st/chapter-3/layer-basics)

So it's gone...Now you use filtering at top right of the layer menu:

[image]

Comment: this will do :)